# Title bar & Nautilus not theming in Unity in 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, themes, icon-themes

Have seen numerous posts on this, but the only solution reported to work (adding a delay to the gnome settings daemon plugin) doesn't work.

Ubuntu 16.04 in a VMWare Workstation 12 VM.

1. Installed fresh copy of Ubuntu
2. Copied custom theme into ~/.themes
3. Copied custom icons into /usr/share/icons
4. Changed theme and icons via Unity Tweak Tool

Everything looked fine until a reboot.

After reboot, title bar and Nautilus wouldn't theme:

[image: Toggling themes in Ubuntu; title bar not changing]

Checked dconf org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings & it's 'active' as it should be.

Kind of stumped, welcoming any ideas!

Comment: If you go back to using one of the standard Ubuntu themes/icons, does it work again?

Comment: nope :/ i mean, the theme the title bars are stuck in is the default, so switching to default makes them technically 'work,' but they're still stuck at default.

Comment: Oh. If you choose another theme... one that ISN'T in your ~/.themes folder... in other words, another theme that comes with Ubuntu, does that work after a reboot. If so, maybe you've got a permissions problem on your ~/.themes folder, or it contents, or with the icons that you put info /usr/share/icons.

Comment: thanks @heynnema - unfortunately permissions are all squared-away.  any changes i make to the themes (to factory themes or ~/.themes) persist after reboot, but the title bar & Nautilus still aren't affected. In other words, no matter the theme, selecting it has the effects illustrated in the .gif above.